# Multicam in Adobe Premiere when sources are split in several files

Tags: premiere, multi-camera

My cameras and my audio recorders don't give me a single file from a recording session, but instead, I get many sequential clips. I'm trying to create a multi-cam sequence in Adobe Premiere with the 3 cameras and a single high-quality audio track. For reference, the video came for GoPro Hero 9 Black and the audio from a Tascam DR-10L. My sources look like this:

[image]

If I just select everything and create a multi-cam sequence, I end with 15 cameras, so what I did was merge all the clips from each camera into a single sequence (I ended up with 3 of those, one for each GoPro), and then use those for the multi-cam. Is that the correct way to handle the video? It seems to work. This is how it ends up looking:

[image]

The audio is proving trickier. If I merge the 3 audio files (the ones with the _D suffix I'm not using) into a single sequence, it ends up being a video clip, not an audio clip (if that makes sense):

[image]

The problem with that is that multi-cam treats it as a video source, not as the master audio source:

[image]

As you can see there, the mic ended up being camera 4, and the master audio is camera 1's terrible audio.

What I tried next was to do a multi-cam with the merged camera clips and the source audio clips (had to skip the 3rd one because there wasn't any overlap, I was already turning cameras off). The problem when I do that is that I end up with two audio tracks instead of one, and they are both only coming through the left channel:

[image]

My settings when creating that last multi-cam are these:

[image]

The audio from the Tascam DR-10L is mono, while the audio from the cameras is stereo. I'm happy to work in mono, so I selected all clips and switched them to mono:

[image]

So, the question is, how do I handle the audio? How do I make a working multi-cam out of all of this with mono sound coming through both channels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On https://premierepro.net/multicam/ it says:

> Many users get audio problems (all tracks panned left) because they’re
> creating a new sequence from the Multicam. Don’t. Create a new
> sequence manually, then drag your Multicam into that sequence.

Creating the sequence manually and then placing the multicam helped solve this problem.